# Finds related data from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

These are the two table structure of my db

```
-- Table structure for table `gf_actor`


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gf_actor` (
  `actor_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `actor_name` varchar(100) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`actor_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `actor_name` (`actor_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;



-- Table structure for table `gf_film_actor`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gf_film_actor` (
  `film_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `actor_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  KEY `film_id` (`film_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

So i need a query which fetches five related actors name and id from gf_actor table who is having acted in movies which was performed by the actor_id lets say actor_id=1 and movies must be different that means five related actors must be acted in different movies with the actor_id=1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select ga.actor_id, actor_name from gf_actor ga inner join gf_film_actor gf on ga.actor_id = gf.actor_id where gf.film_id in (select gf1.film_id from gf_film_actor gf1 where  gf1.actor_id=1) AND gf.actor_id != 1 LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Looks like you will get nothing after running this script, because in such structure we always have only one actor for a film

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong table structure. It should be like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gf_actor` (
  `actor_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `actor_name` varchar(100) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`actor_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `actor_name` (`actor_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gf_film` (
  `film_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `performed_by_actor_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  KEY `film_id` (`film_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gf_film_actor` (
  `film_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `actor_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  KEY `film_actor_id` (`film_id`, `actor_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And now you can create your query like this:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM `gf_film` AS f
  LEFT JOIN `gf_film_actor` AS fa ON f.`film_id` = fa.`film_id`
  LEFT JOIN `gf_actor` AS a ON fa.`actor_id` = a.`actor_id`
 WHERE f.`performed_by_actor_id` = 1
 LIMIT 0, 5;
```